# How many combinations can one make with the following 8 letter word?

Tags: probability, statistics

Determine the amount of different 3 character combinations you can form with the characters from SEQUENCE.

I imagine the solution is $8*7*6$ but EEE and EEE are not invalid, and EEN and EEN are also the same.  I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Is EEN the same as ENE and NEE?

Comment: No, EEN is different from ENE and NEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We separate into **cases**.

Our word will have (a) $3$ E's, or (b) $2$ E's, or (c) $1$ or $0$ E's.

(a) There is only $1$ word of this type.

(b) The *location* of the E's can be chosen in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways. For each such choice, there are $5$ ways to select the remaining letter, for a total of $15$.

(c) We have $6$ distinct letters available. They can be arranged in $(6)(5)(4)$ ways.

Add up. We get $136$.

Comment: If say NEE is different from ENE, shouldn't we use permutations instead of combinations when we multiply our case?

Comment: In counting "permutations" where there are repetitions, often "combination" symbols can be useful. I will count the number of "exactly $2$ E's" words in a way slightly different from the one used in the answer. There are $5$ non-E's. So we can choose the non-E in $5$ ways. For each of these ways, the chosen letter can be put in any one of $3$ places. Now where the E's go is determined. That gives use $(5)(3)$ words with exactly two E's. Or else you could do it the long way, by explicitly listing all the two E words. You will get $15$.

Answer (score 1):

You have 8 symbols of which 3 are repeats. Of these you are selecting 3 symbols to arrange.

Count the permutations having no, one, two, and three E.

$${5 \choose 3}\frac{3!}{0!} + {5 \choose 2}\frac{3!}{1!}+ {5 \choose 1}\frac{3!}{2!}+{5 \choose 0}\frac{3!}{3!} = 136$$

[edit]

If the order of selection is not important, then it is:

$${5 \choose 3} + {5 \choose 2} + {5 \choose 1} + {5 \choose 0} = 56$$

[/edit]

---

Case 1: For none of the E, select 3 of the 5 remaining letters. There are ${5\choose 3}$ distinct ways to select these and $3!$ ways to arrange the selected letters.

Case 2: With 1 E, select 2 of the 5 remaining letters.  There are ${5\choose 2}$ ways to select these and $3!$ ways to arrange the selected letters.

Case 3: With 2 selected, select 1 of the 5 remaining letters.  There are ${5\choose 1}$ ways to select these and $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways to arrange the selected letters.

Case 4: With all of the 3 E, you can select none of the remaining letters.  There are $1$ ways to select these and $1$ way to arrange the selected letters.

This counts all the ways to distinctly select and arrange three of the eight letters in the string "SEQUENCE".

Comment: Shouldn't we subtract that value from 8*7*6? Because those are all the possibilities from the string.

Comment: No @Jason.  For each $k\in\{9,1,2,3\}$, you select $k$ of 3 E, select $3-k$ of the 5 others others, and permutate $3$ symbols with $k$ repeats.  _That_ counts all the possible permutations.

Comment: When we select the remainder of the letters (the 5), shouldn't we use permutations instead of combinations if say NEE were different from EEN?

Comment: Yes, and we are selecting the two combinations, then determining the permutations of all selected; that's the last term.